# How to Email execution report in selenium web-driver java without jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to use apache common mail API. the code i used is
public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException {

```
    System.out.print("-------Start------");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(userName, password));
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject("TestMail");
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
    email.addTo("myemail@gmail.com");
    email.send();
    System.out.print("-------End------");
}
```

but It is saying username and password not accepted however i am providing the correct credentials. When i opened my gmail account , it is showing that it has blocked the sign in attempt. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please download https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases

And follow the example below on how to setup Gmail using JavaMail.  You dont need any webdriver for this.  The javamail jar in your classpath is sufficient.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendEmailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS
        
        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("to_username_a@gmail.com, to_username_b@yahoo.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Testing Gmail TLS");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n Please do not spam my email!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If still having trouble, you might need to use and trust an APP Password.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?p=InvalidSecondFactor

```
Create & use App Passwords

If you use 2-Step-Verification and get a "password incorrect" error when you sign in, you can try to use an App Password.

    Go to your Google Account.
    Select Security.
    Under "Signing in to Google," select App Passwords. You may need to sign in. If you don’t have this option, it might be because:
        2-Step Verification is not set up for your account.
        2-Step Verification is only set up for security keys.
        Your account is through work, school, or other organization.
        You turned on Advanced Protection.
    At the bottom, choose Select app and choose the app you using and then Select device and choose the device you’re using and then Generate.
    Follow the instructions to enter the App Password. The App Password is the 16-character code in the yellow bar on your device.
    Tap Done.

Tip: Most of the time, you’ll only have to enter an App Password once per app or device, so don’t worry about memorizing it.
```

Reference: https://mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/